# Compile error with generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, compiler-errors, extends

There's the following class:

```
public class LivingBeing { … }
```

Then there's

```
public class Human extends LivingBeing { … }
```

Now there's also this wrapper:

```
public class LivingBeingWrapper<T extends LivingBeing> { … }
```

And to complete the picture there's also the method

```
public boolean validate(LivingBeingWrapper<LivingBeing> livingBeingWrapper)
```

Now when writing the following code

```
LivingBeingWrapper<Human> wrapper = createHumanWrapper();
validate(wrapper);
```

I get the following compile error:

> The method validate(LivingBeingWrappe<LivingBeing>
>   livingBeingWrapper) in the type MyType is not applicable for the
>   arguments (LivingBeingWrapper<Human>).

But why? `Human` extends `LivingBeing`.

Comment: `<LivingBeing>` means only LivingBeing, `<? extends LivingBeing>` means it can extend LivingBeing. e.g. Human.

Comment: I think you're suffering from type erasure... Still, +1 for a well structured question

Comment: can you try: `public boolean validate(LivingBeingWrapper<? extends LivingBeing> livingBeingWrapper)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `validate` method declares that it must be called with a `LivingBeingWrapper` parameterised with `LivingBeing`.  However, you're passing in a `LivingBeingWrapper` parameterised with `Human`.  Try changing your method declaration from this:

```
public boolean validate(LivingBeingWrapper<LivingBeing> livingBeingWrapper)
```

to this:

```
public boolean validate(LivingBeingWrapper<? extends LivingBeing> livingBeingWrapper)
```

Answer (score 6):

A banana **is-a** fruit. But a list of bananas **is not a** list of fruit. Otherwise you could take a list of bananas and add an apple (given that an apple **is-a** fruit).

That sounds rather gnomic, but it's key to what's happening above. You need to specify your wrapper such that it takes types extending `LivingBeing`.

For further info, see [this article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html), and in particular the "Generics are not Covariant" section.

Comment: I love this explanation.  If you add concrete advice too, I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change your below method: -

```
public boolean validate(LivingBeingWrapper<LivingBeing> livingBeingWrapper)
```

to

```
public boolean validate(LivingBeingWrapper<T> livingBeingWrapper)
```

Since this method is inside your class which is like: -

```
public class LivingBeingWrapper<T extends LivingBeing>
```

So, you can use the type T in your method parameter, and T will be replaced by `Horse`.. For your particular reference..

And if your method **takes some different type** than the one in `class definition (T)`, then you can use this declaration: -

```
public boolean validate(LivingBeingWrapper<? extends LivingBeing> 
                                                    livingBeingWrapper)
```

Now, if you have to call **`validate(LivingBeingWrapper<Human>)`**, your method has to be defined to take generic type parameter type `Human`, which extends `LivingBeing`, which is what your `T` type is (As it also extends LivingBeing in your class definition)

Comment: `validate` isn't a method on `LivingBeingWrapper`.

Comment: You're using `T`.  But `validate` isn't necessarily a method on a parameterized class.

Comment: @DavidGrant.. Yeah that I assumed that it is inside that class.. So, I have mentioned it..  Edited post to add that part..